# Cursor at very start of first line in Draft.js editor

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have an `onUpArrow` handler that needs to check whether the cursor is at the very beginning of the first line in a Draft.js editor. The editor may contain multiple lines/blocks.

I found that `SelectionState` methods such as `getAnchorOffset()` and `getStartOffset()` can tell me that the cursor is at the start of a line by returning `0`, but that value is returned at the start of any line/block, not just the first one in the editor.

This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/40#issuecomment-189258555) makes reference to "get start or end of document or to get the exact cursor position" but it doesn't appear this made it into the Draft source.

Does anyone know a way to detect whether the cursor is at the very start of the editor content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your check, and this `editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlockMap().first().getKey() === selectionState.getAnchor/FocusKey()`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. In case it helps anyone, `getFocusKey()` was the method needed at the end (`getAnchorKey()` returns `true` for all lines when the cursor is at the start of the line).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I use the standard [handleKeyCommand](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor.html#handlekeycommand) function to detect whether or not I am at the **start** of the **first line** of a DraftJS editor:

```
handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {

  const selectionState = editorState.getSelection()

  const firstline = (editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlockMap().first().getKey() == selectionState.getFocusKey())

  const startofline = (selectionState.getAnchorOffset() == 0)

  if (firstline && startofline) {
    // Your caret is at the start of the first line of your DraftJS editor.
  }
}
```